# Ignore a certain layer when using OnPointerDown()

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine

In my 2D top-down game, I have a Script I attach to NPCs to control when the player clicks them, starting a dialogue.

However, the way I've decided to design this is that I have an extra collider on my player called `InteractiveArea`, and you can only interact with NPCs inside that area. On `Start` I add:

```
 Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(LayerMask.NameToLayer("InteractiveArea"), LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));
```

to make sure it doesn't collide with my player.

So, the problem I'm facing is that my `MousePointer` picks up the `InteractiveArea` collider, and not the NPCs, so if the NPC is inside the `InteractiveArea` my method won't work:

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (npcManager.currentlyInteractable) //set to true when inside InteractiveArea
    {
        if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
        {
            npcManager.Clicked();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make the `InteractiveArea` ignore my `MousePointer`, like I do with my player on Start? Or maybe my entire system with using an `InteractiveArea` is poor design and I should do something else to control this? Just seemed a very neat and simple solution.

Comment: I believe raycasts can ignore layers, you can use raycast to see if NPC is clicked. Other than that for InteractiveArea, you can store the distances between NPCs and Player in an array, and check if the distance is satisfied to start a conversation.

Comment: Yeah I tried ignoring the Layer but had no success. Maybe I did it wrong. If you know how please post an Answer. The confusing thing is I use the same approach on some other Object in my game you can click when inside interactive Area. And for those the InteractiveArea does not block.

Comment: Turns out if I change InteractiveArea Z to 1 instead of 0 it works. Not sure if that is the best way to go about it tho.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already found a hack for this, which is not the best way to do this. So I decided to answer this anyway:

You don't need to use collider to define the interactive area for player and the whole implementation of `npcManager.currentlyInteractable`.

There are different ways to do this without using collider:

### 1. Check the Distance

A distance between player and NPC can be checked before interacting like this:

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position)    

        if (distance < 2) // player is close enough
        {
            npcManager.Clicked();
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. Check for Collider Bounds in Radius

[`Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html) can be used to detect if player collider is overlapping a circle of certain radius:

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
    {
        Vector2 center = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z) // use y component depending on how you setup top-down view
        float raduis = 2f;

        Collider2D[] collidersInCircle = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(center, raduis);

        foreach (var collider in collidersInCircle)
        {
            if(collider.CompareTag("Player")) // player must have appropriate tag
            {
                npcManager.Clicked();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: first solution is really neat, just need to add the player to the script which I cant do in the inspector so I'd have to do like find object with Tag or something, which I dont love, but I guess its fine :)

Comment: Just fetch and store the reference of player using `FindObjectOfType<Player>()` in start method ;)

Comment: It doesn't really matter as you are only using it once (in start method). Do not use it in Update/FixedUpdate method ever. It doesn't matter too if there is only 1 object in the scene with that certain tag or type. I personally prefer `FindObjectOfType` to avoid writing strings hence to avoid typos :)